# Uploading image with Almofire 4 swift 3

Tags: swift, alamofire, image-uploading

i want to upload photo into server with almofire i'm using this code right now but i'm getting timeout

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 1)

let urlRequest = self.urlRequestWithComponents(url, imageData: imageData!)
self.alamofire.upload(urlRequest.1, to: urlRequest.0 as! URLConvertible).responseJSON { response in
    guard response.result.isSuccess else {
        self.showError()
        return
    }

    guard let data = response.result.value else {
        self.showError()
        return
    }

    let json = JSON(data)
}

func urlRequestWithComponents(_ urlString:String, imageData:Data) -> (URLRequestConvertible, Data) {
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary
    urlRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    uploadData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    uploadData.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    uploadData.append(imageData)
    uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    return try! (Alamofire.URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: nil), uploadData as Data)
}
```

Is there any solution about this issue ?

Comment: kindly response to my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this in swift 3

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "photo_path", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }, to:"http://server1/upload_img.php")
{ (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in
            //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
            //self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
        print(encodingError)
    }

}
```

Comment: "http://server1/upload_img.php" Is your image location path or it's API function file path ??

Comment: @Bhavin_m No Its my API URL